# Round in MS SQL on 0.05 or 0.00

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

Hello I am coming from Bosnia and Herzegovina and in our county the smallest  note bill is 0.05, 
Now the government pushing us to our retrial prices rounding on 0.05 or at 0.00.
Therefor I want to create SQL Scalar Valued Function for rounding the prices on given value.
Is there some build in solution so I can save resource of my queries.
Thanx in advice
Best regards

Edit from comment:

- 0,1,2,3,4 go to zero
- 5,6,7,8,9 going to zero+1

Comment: 8,9,0,1,2 go to zero?  3,4,5,6,7 go to 5?

Comment: Simething like this or 0,1,2,3,4 go to zero and 5,6,7,8,9 going to zero+1

Comment: We round in Switzerland too but this is rounding down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to marc_s, i changed to money datatype.

[float vs decimal vs money datatype article and flowchart](http://sqlcat.com/technicalnotes/archive/2008/09/25/the-many-benefits-of-money-data-type.aspx)

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.ufnRound (@number money)
RETURNS money
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN FLOOR(@number*20) / 20
END
GO
SELECT dbo.ufnRound (1.22), dbo.ufnRound (1.23), dbo.ufnRound (1.27), dbo.ufnRound (1.28)

-- gives    1.2    1.2   1.25   1.25
```

Comment: Aren't you missing something still? YOu're rounding 1.27 to 1.25 - as far as I understood the post, you should be rounding that UP to 1.30 - no?

Comment: OP's comment contradicts the original text though... we round differently here (your locations)

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing built-in - but it's easy enough to create:

EDIT : adapted to your special rounding needs :-)

```
create function dbo.RoundToFiveOrZero(@inputValue MONEY)
returns MONEY
as begin
  return FLOOR((@inputValue + 0.05) * 20.0) / 20.0
end
```

Use the DECIMAL or MONEY data type - whatever suits you best.

Use it like this:

```
select 
    dbo.RoundToFiveOrZero(1.51),
    dbo.RoundToFiveOrZero(1.53),
    dbo.RoundToFiveOrZero(7.33),
    dbo.RoundToFiveOrZero(7.37),
    dbo.RoundToFiveOrZero(7.39)
```

Which gives you 1.50, 1.50, 7.30, 7.40, 7.40 as results.

Marc