# MS SQL Server decimal data type rounds up

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, types, decimal

I need to be able to store numbers like 3.5 in my table. So I've used the decimal type field. But if I enter 3.5 it round it up to 4. Am I being stupid or is it not the point of decimal to have a decimal point?

Comment: Why you do not use [FLOAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx), And if You need to round always numbers to 0.0 or 0.5 take [look at this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752655/round-in-ms-sql-on-0-05-or-0-00)

Comment: yup that worked, I just though FLOAT was for massive numbers. Thinks I need to get my head around data types again. thanks adopilot!

Comment: @Jonesy - just make sure you understand the difference between FLOATs and DECIMALs as they are not the same. FLOAT is approximate: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx vs DECIMAL reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx

Comment: Can you post the full definition of the decimal column (i.e. the scale and precision you've used) e.g. DECIMAL(10, 2) - 10=precision, 2=scale. Also, how are you entering the number - into a UI? In an SQL statement? Could you post that up too?

Comment: Float is a very bad idea if you plan to do math onthe value. It will cause rounding errors as it is not an exact value. Very bad recommendation.

Answer (score 16):

You need to declare it like **decimal(18,3)** to specify the number of digits after the point.

In case you are using stored procedure parameter also must have precision specified next to **decimal**, e.g. **decimal(18,3)**

Comment: yeah it was declared as decimal(18,3). Not sure why I rounded it.

Comment: How did you put data?
Maybe you are using stored procedure - than parameter also should have type decimal(18,3), not just decimal.