# Rounding up a number so that it is divisible by 5

Tags: c#, math

I want to round up a number (decimal) so that it's divisible by 5.

For example, I have a few numbers and the numbers after rounding up:

```
Number        Rounded
0.4           5
3.4           5
7.3           10
```

I can use `ceil` to convert this `double` to `int` and use a `while` loop to get them to the next multiple of 5, but I was wondering if there is any clever way of accomplishing this.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your input a `decimal` or a `double` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752655/round-in-ms-sql-on-0-05-or-0-00 Here is solution for SQL

Answer (score 41):

You could first divide by 5 and then use [Math.Ceiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/1cz5da1c.aspx) to round the value. Afterwards, u can multiply by 5 again.

```
int rounded = (int) Math.Ceiling(Number / 5) * 5
```

Comment: since `rounded` is int, wont type casting be automatic?

Comment: i don't think a double to int cast can be automatic - it always has to be explicit.

Answer (score 10):

If you want

```
 f[6]  =  10
 f[-1] =  0  
 f[-6] = -5
```

[Sören's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874943/rounding-up-a-number-so-that-it-is-divisible-by-5/4874984#4874984) is OK.

If instead you want:

```
 f[6]  =  10
 f[-1] =  -5 
 f[-6] = -10
```

you could do something like:

```
f[x_] := Sign[x] Ceiling[Abs[x]/5] * 5
```

C#:

```
var rounded = (int) Math.Sign(x) * Math.Ceiling(Math.Abs(x)/5) * 5;
```

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
5 * decimal.Ceiling(num / 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the stated answers are fine, but if you're in need of performance, I doubt you're going to get anything faster than this in C#:

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(input);
return (i % 5) == 0 ? i : i + 5 - (i % 5);
```

Quick tests in LinqPad shows this runs on average roughly 50% faster than the quickest of the answers given so far. This is if you are starting with a decimal as the OP asked.

If you are running with integers to start with, the first line is unnecessary and the return statement runs roughly 17 times faster than the closest competitor.